# Should PATH and VIRTUAL_ENV environment variables be set in systemd service unit config for gunicorn to serve a Flask app?

Tags: python, virtualenv, gunicorn, systemd

When serving a Flask app with gunicorn, I assume I should activate the venv before `gunicorn myapp:app`, since gunicorn is installed in the venv along with other packages and codes comprising the app. In the scenario of using `flask run` or `python myapp.py` to run the app, the venv needs to be activated first (in every tutorial and book I've read), so it seems to me that there's no reason the gunicorn case be different.

Then when it comes to making gunicorn a systemd service unit, as I know no way in this scenario to "activate a venv" as in interactive shell, the closest thing I can think of is to put `Environment="PATH=/PathToMyApp:other_default_path_var_contents"` and `Environment="VIRTUAL_ENV=/PathToMyApp/.venv"` in the config, along with `ExecStart=/PathToMyApp/.venv/bin/gunicorn myapp:app`.

However, I found that almost none of the tutorials I read bothers to add these Environment options as I thought. Are those tutorials just wrong about this, or the environment variables are insignificant regarding gunicorn in a virtual environment? If it's the latter, why is that? What's the difference from `flask run` and `python myapp.py` cases?

Comment: Running a system service in a virtual environment would be a rather unusual arrangement. If you are running in a system context, just install your dependencies system-wide.

Comment: @tripleee For me it doesn't make sense that just because being managed by systemd, same python codes become "not supposed to run in virtual env". Because, if I haven't understood it incorrectly, virtual env is meant to solve system-wide package version conflict issue, which is totally possible to happen when two or more software, all written in python, need to automatically start/restart using systemd. Moreover, in this case, it's just a web app to serve incoming HTTP requests. It seems totally reasonable to serve two web apps from same host, each with its dependencies properly maintained.

Comment: I'm not saying it can't or shouldn't be done, just explaining why it's uncommon. Though if you genuinely have this need, probably your understanding should not be based solely on what you can find in random blog posts and forums.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the official gunicorn docs, the section on [`systemd`](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html#systemd) says you should define:

```
WorkingDirectory=/PathToMyApp
ExecStart=/PathToMyApp/.venv/bin/gunicorn myapp:app
```

This should be enough without having to set `PATH` or `VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variables.

> Are those tutorials just wrong about this, or the environment variables are insignificant regarding gunicorn in a virtual environment? If it's the latter, why is that? What's the difference from flask run and python myapp.py cases?

When you run `python myapp.py` with the virtual env activated at your shell it's actually running the python interpreter which is in the virtual env's `bin` directory.  You can demonstrate this as follows:

This will show your system Python:

```
/tmp $ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

Activate the venv:

```
/tmp $ . venv/bin/activate
(venv) /tmp $
```

This will show the python interpreter in the venv:

```
(venv) /tmp $ which python
/tmp/venv/bin/python
```

Furthermore when you `cat venv/bin/gunicorn` the bang line points to the python interpreter in that venv:

```
#!/tmp/venv/bin/python3
```

So when you specify this in your `systemd` unit file as `ExecStart` (or execute `venv/bin/gunicorn` directly without the venv activated) it's actually running that with `venv/bin/python3`, which in turn makes all the dependencies installed in that venv available to the process.

Comment: Of course I know by activating a venv we use its python interpreter instead of the system one, and same with gunicorn in the venv. I asked the question because [virtualenv user guide](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/#activate-script) mentioned the two environment variables and I was wondering if they have other significance. Now I guess in pure web app scenario where all python codes run in the same process, no subprocess involved, they affect nothing. By the way gunicorn docs regarding systemd doesn't consider virtual env case at all (ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn xxx.wsgi).